Opengraph image is not global in nextjs
I have defined my opengraph metadata in layout.tsx in my NextJs app directory.

const pageTitle = {
  template: "%s | Oasis of Ideas",
  default: "Oasis of Ideas | Share & discover ideas for any kind of project.",
};

const pageDescription: string =
  "Share ideas for projects you would like someone to do. Discover great ideas to pursue for yourself.";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  // things that search engines see
  metadataBase: new URL("https://www.oasis-of-ideas.com"),
  title: pageTitle,
  description: pageDescription,
  keywords: [
    "ideas",
    "apps",
    "business",
    "startup",
    "projects",
    "discussion",
    "new",
    "unique",
    "feasible",
    "innovation",
    "collaboration",
    "discussion",
    "community",
  ],
  publisher: "Team Oasis",

  // things that show up on the social media previews
  openGraph: {
    type: "website",
    url: "/",
    title: pageTitle,
    description: pageDescription,
    images: [
      {
        url: "/website-preview.png",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        alt: "Oasis of Ideas Open Graph Image",
      },
    ],
  },
  twitter: {
    card: "summary_large_image",
    // title, description not required as it defaults to og:title and og:description
    images: [
      {
        url: "/website-preview.png",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        alt: "Oasis of Ideas Website Preview",
      },
    ],
    site: "@oasis_of_ideas", // Indicates the Twitter account for the website or platform on which the content was published
  },
  icons: {
    icon: "/favicon.ico", // the small icon shown on the browser tabs
    apple: "/apple-touch-icon.png", // small icon shown on pages when saved to home
  },
  manifest: "/site.webmanifest", // specifies data if page is saved to home screen
};


Now I have defined my metadata for another page as follows

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Repository of project ideas",
  openGraph: {
    title: "Repository of project ideas",
  },
};

Now the opengraph image for this page is not showing up whereas when I remove this export then it shows up so somehow it is overriding instead it should take image from layout.tsx if it's not defined here.
I tried to do it in a fresh project to check if there's issue in my project but it turned out that this issue exits.
